# XHR request for Image Fails On Second Request in Safari

Tags: javascript, image, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, cors

I am storing image assets on S3 and requesting them using an XHR. I have a CORS policy file on S3 that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Everything is working great in Chrome and Firefox, but I've got problems in Safari ...

If I clear my cache and request an image, there is no problem and the image loads successfully, however if I then refresh the page, the image fails to load and I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/my.bucket.com/photographs/example.jpg?1369324610.
>   Origin http://example.dev is not allowed by
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Using Charles to watch the network, I can see that on this second request, *no request is made to S3*.

So the problem seems related to Safari's cache.

**Does anyone have any idea why I'm getting this error in Safari?**

The loading code is part of a library called [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS/documentation) and the class responsible for loading is [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/master/src/preloadjs/XHRLoader.js). p_createXHR starting on Line 370 contains the XHR creation code. However, having kept a close eye on this function, the XHR request appears to be identical between succeeding and failing requests.

Comment: Show us the code you use to request the image.

Comment: @idbehold The code is in a library called [PreloadJS](http://www.createjs.com/#!/PreloadJS/documentation)  and the class responsible for loading is [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/blob/master/src/preloadjs/XHRLoader.js). p_createXHR starting on Line 370 contains the XHR creation code.